# Show alert message when wrong date typed in

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, date, input

I have set the date type input to display calendar with date not less than 18 years to avoid user choosing date that is less than 18 years old. But the problem is the user still able to manually type in a wrong date. Is there a way to show an alert message and empty the input when a date less than 18 years is typed in?

```
           $(function(){
                var dtToday = new Date();
            
                var month = dtToday.getMonth() + 1;// jan=0; feb=1 .......
                var day = dtToday.getDate();
                var year = dtToday.getFullYear() - 18;
                if(month < 10)
                    month = '0' + month.toString();
                if(day < 10)
                    day = '0' + day.toString();
                var minDate = year + '-' + month + '-' + day;
                var maxDate = year + '-' + month + '-' + day;
                $('#emp_dob').attr('max', maxDate);
            });

 <div class="form-group">
        <label>Date of Birth</label>
        <input type="date" name="emp_dob" id="emp_dob" class="form-control">
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I infer you are using jquery, so it's pretty easy, you need to do the following:

1. Define in which HTML tag you want to show this alert box.
2. Make the checkup.
3. Print the message.

```js
if (year < 18) {
  $('.error-div').html("You can't choose less than 18 years");
}
```

You can also use $.append.

Check the following links:

- https://api.jquery.com/html/
- https://api.jquery.com/append/#append-content-content
- https://api.jquery.com/text/#text

Use the one that better fits your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You already have the date picker not allowing a selection of a Date less than 18 years from today's date. So IMHO it doesn't seem feasible to have an alert for a selection that isn't possible.

But, if you would like to do that, you must create a new condition like so:

```
if ( year < 18 ) {
   alert("You must be 18 years of age");
}
```

```js
           $(function(){
                var dtToday = new Date();
            
                var month = dtToday.getMonth() + 1;// jan=0; feb=1 .......
                var day = dtToday.getDate();
                var year = dtToday.getFullYear() - 18;
                if(month < 10)
                    month = '0' + month.toString();
                if(day < 10)
                    day = '0' + day.toString();
                var minDate = year + '-' + month + '-' + day;
                var maxDate = year + '-' + month + '-' + day;
                $('#emp_dob').attr('max', maxDate);
            });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
 <div class="form-group">
        <label>Date of Birth</label>
        <input type="date" name="emp_dob" id="emp_dob" class="form-control">
    </div>
```

Comment: so do i have to add the line you suggested after this line "                $('#emp_dob').attr('max', maxDate); "?

Answer (score 0):

Every HTML `<input>` element fires a series of events. For instance if you add an change event listener to your date input, it would fire as soon as the user inputs something. So the basic idea is we catch if the user entered something and compare the input to a target date - in your case sometime before 18 years. The problem with this is that the event would fire every time the user changes a single number, not just once if the entire date is set. What we need to do instead is waiting for a press of the return key, as it's used to actually set the chosen date.

Inside the callback function we can compare the date to the target date and act accordingly - e.g. display an alert box.

Here's an example:

```js
let minDate = new Date("2003-07-21");
document.getElementById("emp_dob").addEventListener("keyup", function(e) {
  if (e.key == "Enter") {
    if (new Date(e.target.value) > minDate) {
      alert("Wrong date!");
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
  <label>Date of Birth</label>
  <input type="date" name="emp_dob" id="emp_dob" class="form-control">
</div>
```